# Django Response Delay for every request

Tags: django, performance, fastcgi

currently, I move my Django application on a production server. The problem is that each request to the server is slower by 1 second, then locallhost. (I don't mean static files. For testing I made ​​a simple VIEW, that not access the database and not contain python code only return string) I did get this values(delay 1 second) ​​of Chrome / Network/ Property - request - Waiting. Property Sending/receiving is normal (cca 1-10ms)

My .htaccess:

```
AuthType none
Satisfy Any
Allow from All

AddHandler fast-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite.cgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

My mysite.cgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import sys, os

# to suppress browser output, you should explicitly say so.
import cgitb
cgitb.enable(display=True)

# Add a custom Python path.

# Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable.
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE","Web.settings")


from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="False")
```

I'm not server admin, so haven´t permission for setting Apache etc.
It is possible that the application not uses FastCGI but CGI? Or something like that?

Thanks

Comment: You'll really need to ask the server admin. I suppose you don't have access to error logs, either?

Comment: Unfortunately not.. Anyway, do you think the problem may be in cgi/fcgi? Because when a rename mysite.CGI on mysite.FCGI, so server give me response (when i put file directly as url):"../mysite.FCGI/.. not found". It seems that files with .fcgi are not executable..

Comment: Well, the file should have the `.fcgi` extension, because you are adding a handler for `.fcgi`. Did you get the handler name `fast-script` from your server admin?

Comment: No handler from admin was original name: fcgid-script .fcgi. But in Django documentation I found, that name is "AddHandler fast-script .fcgi" So a renamed it..

Comment: I guess that [your server uses mod_fcgid](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#using-mod-fcgid-as-alternative-to-mod-fastcgi), so you need to [adjust your configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html) accordingly, and keep the `fcgid-script` handler name

Comment: See also: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#running-django-on-a-shared-hosting-provider-with-apache

Comment: Ok thanks, I change back handler on: fcgid-script .fcgi I'll contact administrator to check Apache configuration by your links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by server admin, the server has not installed mod_fcgid.